# Rehashing a hash table comprised of a vector of lists C++

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, hashtable

So I have implemented a hash table storing pointers. I implemented it as a `vector` of `lists`. Along the lines of `std::vector<std::list<Sequence*> > hashTable;`. I have implemented everything and it works fine. My only problem arises when I try to rehash the hash table. The hash table uses separate chaining to resolve collisions, hence my vector of lists.

Using the debugger, I have found that my loop to rehash is hanging on the while loop and causing an infinite loop. It constantly reads from the first index of my old vector. I am new to this and I am not sure of the proper way to rehash this table. I tried to research and found not many references to this implementation of a hash table, much less rehashing one. Here is my implementation.

```
void HashTable::rehash(int oldSize){
    int tempSize = 2 * oldSize;
    int newSize = HashTable::findPrime(tempSize);
    std::vector<std::list< Sequence*> > newHashTable;
    newHashTable.resize(newSize);
    tableSize = newSize;
    for(int i = 0; i < oldSize; i++){
        auto iter = hashTable[i].begin();
        while(iter != hashTable[i].end()){
            if((*iter) != nullptr){
                std::string tempString = (*iter)->getKey();
                int hashIndex = hashFunction(tempString);
                newHashTable[hashIndex].push_front(*iter);
            }
        }
    }
    hashTable = newHashTable;
}
```

I feel like it is a simple error, I am just not seeing it. Or am I completely going about this the wrong way?

Comment: is there a reason not to use [`std::unordered_map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/)?

Comment: @m.s. Yes, this is an assignment. I am not allowed to use `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to update `iter`, that's why `iter` will never become `hashtable[i].end()` unless it starts with that value.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed the problem. I don't see how I didn't see that. Although, I have been staring at the code for several hours.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a  `++iter`  before the end of your while loop so it moves on to the next on the list.

I would normally use a for loop myself as it makes me less likely to forget to increment the iterator. Something like:

```
for(auto iter = hashTable[i].begin(); iter != hashTable[i].end(): ++iter)
{
     // ... code using iterator ...
}
```